# Сохранение фалов на сервере и отслеживание не используемых

Tags: php, fileupload, mysql

Как отслеживать загруженные файлы от пользователей?

Пишу нечто типа форума

Любой пользователь сможет загружать неограниченное количество фалов до 3 мб

В итоге как только он загрузил файл то получает ббкод

```
[file=url]
```

И вот проблема, допустим он загрузил файл а потом передумал и не стал стаить ббкод в сообщение

В итоге файл будет лежать на сервере как хлам

Как отслеживать какими фалами пользуются а какими нет при этом не создавая нагрузки на сервер?

Чтобы можно было удалять не используемые файлы

Comment: Например: Ведите список всех загруженных файлов плюс сколько сообщений форума ведет на этот файл и дата загрузки. Если ведет ноль сообщений и дата создания более скажем 2 суток, то файл удаляется.

Comment: Да. Мне лично идея @ReinRaus больше нравится, чем ответ снизу)))
Единственное уточнение - "сколько сообщений форума ведет на этот файл" - думаю считать ссылки стоит при записи/обновлении сообщения. То есть у вас в БД таблица вида [ИДсообщения, ТокенФайлаИзURL, ДатаСохраненияФАЙЛА] и уникальный ключ по первым двум полям. Строго говоря - последнее поле можно не хранить, а проверять собственно по дате создания файла.

Answer (score 2):

Введите счетчик загрузки для каждого файла + дату последнего скачивания, храните это все в базе и исходя из этого придумайте себе правило, после какого порога простоя вы будете удалять файл! Скрипт можно повесить на крон и запускать раз в сутки, большой нагрузки от него не будет!

Answer (score 0):

Сохраняйте загружаемые файлы в отдельную временную директорию. После сохранения сообщения парсите текст и перемещаете на постоянное хранение только нужные файлы. Временную директорию очищаете от оставшихся.

Так же не плохо завести табличку куда записываете заливаемые файлы и указывать к какому сообщению они привязаны. При редактировании сообщения делаем аналогичную процедуру, только добавляем в табличку нужное и удаляем ненужное.